# Problems with updating views in CoreDatat

Tags: swiftui, core-data, relationship

I am relative new to SwiftUI and CoreData. I have set up a quiet simple Model for CoreData. The App should create **Contracts** and every Contract should have an own **Business** and a **Businesspartner**. So I have created the model a the relationships between these, that one Contract could have one business and one businesspartner. In the next step I created my CoreData-Manager like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    static let instance = CoreDataManager()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ContractModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading CD \(error)")
            }
        }
        context = container.viewContext
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving CD. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

class CoreDataRelationshipViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let mangager = CoreDataManager.instance
    @Published var businesses: [BusinessEntity] = []
    @Published var contracts: [ContractEntity] = []
    @Published var businesspartners: [BusinessPartnerEntity] = []
    
    init() {
        getContracts()
        getBusiness()
        getBusinesspartners()
    }
    
    
    //Loadfunction
    func getBusiness() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<BusinessEntity>(entityName: "BusinessEntity")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \BusinessEntity.name, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
           businesses = try mangager.context.fetch(request)
            print("Loaded")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error loading CD Businesses. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func getContracts() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ContractEntity>(entityName: "ContractEntity")
        
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ContractEntity.businesspartner?.name, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
       
        do {
           contracts = try mangager.context.fetch(request)
            print("Loaded")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error loading CD Contracts. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func getBusinesspartners() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<BusinessPartnerEntity>(entityName: "BusinessPartnerEntity")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \BusinessPartnerEntity.name, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
           businesspartners = try mangager.context.fetch(request)
            print("Loaded")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error loading CD Businesspartners. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    
    //_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    //Savefunction
    func addBusiness(name: String) {
        let newBusiness = BusinessEntity(context: mangager.context)
        newBusiness.name = name
        save()
    }
    
    func addVertrag( businessSelected: Int, businesspartnerSelected: Int, contractnumber: String ) {
        getContracts()
        getBusiness()
        getBusinesspartners()
        let newContract = ContractEntity(context: mangager.context)
        newContract.contractNumber = contractnumber
        newContract.business = businesses[businessSelected]
        newContract.businesspartner = businesspartners[businesspartnerSelected]
        save()

    }
    
    func addBusinesspartner(name: String) {

        let newBusinesspartner = BusinessPartnerEntity(context: mangager.context)
        newBusinesspartner.name = name
        save()
    }
    
    
    //_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    //deletefunktion
    func deleteContract(offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.map { contracts[$0] }.forEach(mangager.context.delete)
        save()
    }
    
    func deleteBusinesses(offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.map { businesses[$0] }.forEach(mangager.context.delete)
        save()
    }
    
    func deleteBusinesspartners(offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.map { businesspartners[$0] }.forEach(mangager.context.delete)
        save()
    }
    
    //_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    
    func save() {
        businesses.removeAll()
        contracts.removeAll()
        businesspartners.removeAll()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            self.mangager.save()
            self.getContracts()
            self.getBusiness()
            self.getBusinesspartners()
        }
    }
}
```

Then the views have been created.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ContractApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()
    @State var showCreateNewContractView = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach($vm.contracts) { $contract in
                        CellView(contract: $contract)
                    }.onDelete(perform: vm.deleteContract)
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            //Hier Tapview für das Hinzufügen von Verträgen
                            self.showCreateNewContractView.toggle()
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").font(.system(size: 50))
                        }.padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showCreateNewContractView) {
                                CreateNewContractView(showCreateNewContractView: $showCreateNewContractView).environment(\.managedObjectContext, vm.mangager.container.viewContext)
                            }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct CellView: View {
    @Binding var contract: ContractEntity
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Own Business: \(contract.business?.name ?? "")")
            Text("Businesspartner: \(contract.businesspartner?.name ?? "")")
            Text("Contractnumber: \(contract.contractNumber ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
struct CreateNewContractView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()
    @Binding var showCreateNewContractView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            vm.addBusiness(name: "Apple")
            vm.addBusinesspartner(name: "Foxcon")
            vm.addVertrag(businessSelected: 0, businesspartnerSelected: 0, contractnumber: "123")
            vm.getContracts()
            showCreateNewContractView.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Save")
        }
        Button {
            vm.addBusiness(name: "Microsoft")
            vm.addBusinesspartner(name: "Foxcon")
            vm.addVertrag(businessSelected: 1, businesspartnerSelected: 0, contractnumber: "456")
showCreateNewContractView.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Save 2")
        }
    }
}
```

But I have the problem, that the ContentView does not update after a contract is created. I see the new contracts only when I restart the App, but when I delete one contract via swipe, all contracts dissapear. I am at the end of my knowledge and have tried so many solutions to make the work, but I'm running in some other issues if I get this to work. For example the saving of the business and business partners in a new contract are removed in old contracts

Comment: we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, there is `@FetchRequest` for that

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, go to CreateNewContractView: View and change the `@StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()` to @ObservedObject var vm: CoreDataRelationshipViewModel , you might be resetting the whole View by using two instances of @StateOBject, its supposed to be used once

Also when you make the change make sure to provide proper instance value , where ever the compiler might ask